# MySql user variable ignored

Tags: mysql

The following SQL runs as expected in the workbench, but generates an error "parameter @search must be defined" when I fire it in from a C# application. Can anyone explain this?

```
set @search = 'b%';
select * from country where Name like @search
```

Comment: How do you "fire it in from a C# application"? Can you show your code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL use the `@variable_name` expression as a user defined variable. C# (or the provider - not really sure which) on the other hand uses the `@parameter_name` to annotate parameter placeholder in the query.

If you want to use sql user defined variables, then add the following parameter to the connection string of your .Net connector connection:

```
Allow User Variables=True
```

or

```
AllowUserVariables=True
```

This option was added to [connector v5.2.2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html)

Comment: Cool. Is there any reason to not do this? Why is it switched off by default?

Comment: Since I'm not a developer of MySQL's .net connector, I can only guess that more developers use parameters in the old fashioned `@parameter_name` convention, than MySQL user defined variables.